# Goalseeker Excel different speeds

Tags: vba, excel

I am cycling through thousands of problems with goalseeker using VBA. Strangely if I change some unrelated cells it will make the goalseeker sometimes go 80% faster for the same set of problems. If I open Excel and run goalseeker it will take about ~1-2 seconds per problem but if I just click on a random cell and press enter for example it will run less than half a second per problem(SAME EXACT PROBLEM). I have a feeling there is some secret buffer in the background. I have a workbook with thousands of formula's and sometimes it freezes the screen buffer. Is there any advice on how to resolve this issue? It has nothing to do with the formulas I have tried replicating it with different formulas and I get the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried **Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual** at the beginning of your macro?  This prevents Excel from re-calculating cells while your macro is running.  Of course it's advisable to put it back into Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic at the end of the macro, or before worksheet recalculation is necessary within the macro.

Comment: @n8 I wonder if goalseeker works with Manual Calculation. I should also turn the RTD refresh time to -1 maybe during the goalseek loop.

Comment: @CodeCamper It would be worth a shot to try to see if it speeds it up, then compare results between the normal type of run to see if you come up with the same results both ways.